# Access SMS and Call logs on windows 7 phone

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, sms

I am trying to access sms and call logs to get a copy and send to the server for corporate application. 
Is it possible to read (not intercept) the sms (incoming and outgoing) and call logs on windows 7 device?

Thanks
Ali

Comment: -1 for asking a question that can easily be answered via a quick google search. Nothing personal mind you, but in the future please see to it that your question is one that is valuable to both yourself and the community.

Comment: @PaulHazen, guess what? my google search sent me here.

Comment: LOLz, well if user1046177 ever marks Rowland Shaw's answer as correct, I'll change my vote :) sorry

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to read (not intercept) the sms (incoming and outgoing) and call logs on windows 7 device?

As of Mango, No. There is no documented API for that.

Answer (score 1):

No, the exact reason being that that'd enable the app developers (*all of them*) to steal the user's private data.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations on the personal data exposed to application developers, and this is limited to calendar information, and address book information. For more detail on those, take a look at the classes in the [Microsoft.Phone.UserData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) namespace